# Open ppt or pptx in google Slides and doc or word in google docs in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, powerpoint, google-workspace, doc

I'm developing an app where I need to open ppt, ptx and pdf in google presentations and doc, word and pdf in google doc

I am able to open both apps with an intent with an uri but for that I need the file to be a google workspace file, so that I get the fileId of it

It would be like this:

```
String link = "https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/” + FILE_ID + “/edit";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(link));
startActivity(i);
```

Is there a way I can open the files in the app without having the id?

Or even better, is there a way to convert the files to google workspace files in order to get the id?
It would be ppt and ptx to Slides and word and doc to google docs

Thanks!

Comment: You will need an ID of some sort in order to open the right document

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Do you know what kind of id? Currently I have these files in pptx and docx format in my firebase storage. I want to allow the user to edit them and then get the edited file back

Comment: When you say you have them in firebase, do you mean you have the actual file stored in firebase?

Comment: Yes, I have the ppt or docx file stored inmy firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is facing the same problem, there really isn't a way to display in the google drive file viewer without the file id from a google drive. So, from what I searched, you can't really use this file viewer unless the file is storaged in a google drive.

Answer (score 0):

add full file location after url=

https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=http://example.in/example.ppt